# STM32F7 can't make USB HS work without ULPI

Tags: usb, stm32, usb-device

I'm following a course on USB for STM32 platform. The teacher is using a STM32F4, my board is a STM32F7 (STM32F746G Discovery exactly).

The goal is to develop a USB from scratch, using no library/HAL. The teacher uses the internal USB FS PHY, no external PHY nor ULPI.

The teacher's code is this:

```
    /*
 * Configure USB pins: PB14 ---> USBM ; PB15 ---> USBP
 */
void usbd_pins_init()
{
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOBEN;    // enable GPIOB clock

    // set PB14 and PB15 alternate functions
    GPIOB->AFR[1] &= ~(GPIO_AFRH_AFRH6 | GPIO_AFRH_AFRH7);
    GPIOB->AFR[1] |= ((12UL << GPIO_AFRH_AFRH6_Pos) | (12UL << GPIO_AFRH_AFRH7_Pos));

    // enable alternate function mode for PB14 and PB15:
    GPIOB->MODER &= ~(GPIO_MODER_MODER14 | GPIO_MODER_MODER15);
    GPIOB->MODER |= ((2UL << GPIO_MODER_MODER14_Pos) | (2UL << GPIO_MODER_MODER15_Pos));
}

/*
 * Initialize USB module
 */
void usbd_core_init()
{
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_OTGHSEN;    // enable USB core clock

    // set device mode, use embedded full-speed PHY, set turn-around time (see page 1384 in the reference manual for its value)
    USB_OTG_HS->GUSBCFG &= ~USB_OTG_GUSBCFG_TRDT;
    USB_OTG_HS->GUSBCFG |= (USB_OTG_GUSBCFG_FDMOD | USB_OTG_GUSBCFG_PHYSEL | (9UL << USB_OTG_GUSBCFG_TRDT_Pos));

    // set full-speed mode
    USB_OTG_HS_DEVICE->DCFG &= ~USB_OTG_DCFG_DSPD;
    USB_OTG_HS_DEVICE->DCFG |= (3UL << USB_OTG_DCFG_DSPD_Pos);

    // enable VBUS detection
    USB_OTG_HS->GCCFG |= USB_OTG_GCCFG_VBDEN;

    // unmask some interrupts: start of frame, receive FIFO non-empty, USB suspend, USB reset, enumeration done, IN endpoints, resume/remote wakeup detected
    USB_OTG_HS->GINTMSK |= (USB_OTG_GINTMSK_SOFM | USB_OTG_GINTMSK_RXFLVLM | USB_OTG_GINTMSK_USBSUSPM | USB_OTG_GINTMSK_USBRST
            | USB_OTG_GINTMSK_ENUMDNEM | USB_OTG_GINTMSK_IEPINT | USB_OTG_GINTMSK_WUIM);

    // clear all USB core pending interrupts
    USB_OTG_HS->GINTSTS = 0xFFFFFFFF;

    // unmask USB global interrupt
    USB_OTG_HS->GAHBCFG |= USB_OTG_GAHBCFG_GINT;
}

/*
 * Connect the USB device to the bus
 */
void usbd_connect()
{
    USB_OTG_HS->GCCFG |= USB_OTG_GCCFG_PWRDWN;      // enable USB FS transceiver
    USB_OTG_HS_DEVICE->DCTL &= ~USB_OTG_DCTL_SDIS;          // connect the USB device to the bus
}
```

This is the very first hours of the course, the goal here is to get the computer to detect the USB Device, and get this result: (this is the /var/log/syslog file in linux):

[image]

But this code does not work on my board, and I cannot understand why.

My clock settings are correct, I've checked them on CubeMX and then on the serial communication.

Also, I tried an example code from ST (HID_StandAlone, from the STM32F7Cube package) designed for my board. This example works when using the ULPI configuration, but not when using the HS mode with internal FS PHY, my computer detects no USB device.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: please do not post any pictures of text whenever possible ... post the actual text and format as code

Comment: it is unclear what you want to know ... please add a clear, answerable question

Comment: @jsotola I would like some help to make it work. I've tried a lot of things and I am still blocked

Comment: What did you try then? Do you connect the PC to correct USB connector?

Comment: @Justme so first I have tested the teacher''s code (code above). Then, because it did not work, I've tried the USB examples given by ST. It worked for the USB HS configured with ULPI and the USB FS projects, but not for the USB HS configured with internal PHY project.
Then I started from the USB HS project and simplified the code by getting rid of the code that does not interest me. Here again, it worked in ULPI mode but not in internal PHY mode.

Comment: Then I've tried to play with different settings, testing different clock frequencies, testing different pins initialization based on things I've found on the internet. I've also tested different configuration settings, read all documents related to my board to find some information about this issue: datasheet, programming manual, schematics, but had not found any. I've checked in debug mode that each register worked and got the value I expected them to have. I have no more idea right now...

Comment: I've compared the teacher's board datasheet with my board datasheet, and I found nothing that can explain why we don't get the same result.

Comment: @Justme Yes I am using the OTG FS (not HS) connector. In fact I've tested on both connectors to be sure

Comment: Your code configures PB14 & PB15 (presumably because your teacher's board has those pins as the USB D+ & D- for the STM32F4). According to the [User Manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um1907-discovery-kit-for-stm32f7-series-with-stm32f746ng-mcu-stmicroelectronics.pdf) for your STM32F7 Discovery (page 25), the D+ & D- pins on the USB OTG connecter are connected to your STM32F7's PA11 & PA12. So you'll need to enable your GPIOA clock instead of GPIOB, and configure GPIOA's AFR & MODER.

Comment: @brhans thank you for your help, I have fixed that. It was still not working so there was a second problem. It has been one week I was working on this problem, and I don't know why but I needed to add :

USB_OTG_FS_GLOBAL->GOTGCTL |= USB_OTG_GOTGCTL_BVALOEN;
USB_OTG_FS_GLOBAL->GOTGCTL |= USB_OTG_GOTGCTL_BVALOVAL;

Comment: I have no idea of what it does. It is not written anywhere in the reference manual that these bits are needed. The description of these bits says that it sets the "b-valid signal". I don't know what is this signal, I guess it is in the USB2.0 spec but I've missed it when I read it